# changing prototype Elements set scopes

Tags: javascript, oop

I am wanting to attach into an Elements default property such as innerHTML as a backup under an object that way it does not pollute the Elements properties. so to help give an idea of what I am trying to achieve and what currently works:

```
Element.prototype._backupPropertyDescriptors = {};
Element.prototype._backupProperties = {};

Element.prototype._backupPropertyDescriptors._innerHTML = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype,'innerHTML');

//This is what I want to do but loses Elements scope:
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype._backupProperties,'_innerHTML',Element.prototype._backupPropertyDescriptors._innerHTML);
//the scope has changed from element to _backupProperties so this property fails.

//The working version:
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype,'_innerHTML',Element.prototype._backupPropertyDescriptors._innerHTML);

//the reason for this is I want to be able to manipulate the get and set such as:
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype._backupProperties,'_innerHTML',{configurable:true,enumerable:true,get:function(){console.log('getting',this.innerHTML);return this.innerHTML},set:function(val){console.log('doing something here before setting');this.innerHTML = val;}});
```

The problem with this is once it is inside of backup the `this` statement no longer holds the element...
I know one way to do this would be to use a bind or call but that still poses the how do I get the elements scope... as `this` during define property is the window..

Comment: You can use `this` with the expected value in that getter of yours (and can `.bind()` or `.call()` however you like)

Comment: That said, what you're doing is [really not recommended](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/). Especially, don't expect `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype,'innerHTML');` to work consistently or at all.

Comment: thats old.. http://lea.verou.me/2015/04/idea-extending-native-dom-prototypes-without-collisions/

Comment: so `this` loses its scope and is now `_backupProperties `

Comment: wow.. just realized if I changed _backupProperties to have a getter setter then it would work like the article says..

Comment: That article you linked seems to demonstrate and explain the solution. What is your exact question?

Comment: well I was havin trouble losing the scope but I got it figured it out :)

Comment: Then please [answer your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) or delete it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for anyone looking to try and do this, here is the solution I found :) might be something better out there, but this does work. requires only 3 properties in the prototype and then all others get put inside a single one.

```
Element.prototype._backupPropertyDescriptors = {};
Element.prototype._backupProperties = {};

Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype,'_backupProvider',
{
    writeable:false,
    enumerable:true,
    configurable:true,
    get:function()
    {
        var _backupProperties = this._backupProperties;
        _backupProperties._Element = this;
        return {_Element:this,_backupPropertyDescriptors:this._backupPropertyDescriptors,_backupProperties:_backupProperties};
    }
});
//These first ones set up the main provider and property and descriptor holders.

//then just copy a descriptor:
Element.prototype._backupPropertyDescriptors._innerHTML = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype,'innerHTML');

//and assign it to a new property inside the backupProperties:
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype._backupProvider._backupProperties,'_innerHTML',
{
    enumerable:true,
    configurable:true,
    get:function()
    {
        return this._Element._backupProvider._backupPropertyDescriptors._innerHTML.get.call(this._Element);
    },
    set:function(val)
    {
        console.log('setting html to: ',val);
        this._Element._backupProvider._backupPropertyDescriptors._innerHTML.set.call(this._Element,val);
    }
});

//and if you wanted to do something really crazy.... like overwrite the original..
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype,'innerHTML',
{
    enumerable:true,
    configurable:true,
    get:function()
    {
        return this._backupProvider._backupProperties._innerHTML;
    },
    set:function(val)
    {
        console.log('setting html to: ',val);
        //do some crazy two way template binding here or something else crazy
        this._backupProvider._backupProperties._innerHTML = val;
    }
});
```

that is all.. thanks for the help @Bergi